# Heroku. Sendgrid add-on. There is an Net::SMTPAuthenticationError (535 Authentication failed: account disabled) error when sending emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sendgrid

I've added the Sendgrid add-on for my free app (Ruby on Rails) on Heroku.

The configuration in `production.rb` file:

```
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  host = 'mysterious-badlands-89513.herokuapp.com'
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: host }
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address        => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
    :port           => '587',
    :authentication => :plain,
    :user_name      => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
    :password       => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
    :domain         => 'heroku.com',
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

But when I'm trying to trigger the email sending, the error `Net::SMTPAuthenticationError (535 Authentication failed: account disabled)` occurs.

The app log:

```
2020-04-25T01:09:46.119736+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-04-25T01:09:46.120039+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2020-04-25T01:09:46.119979 #10]  INFO -- : [5ffafd44-806d-40e5-b0cf-fd87bdaaef67] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 820ms (ActiveRecord: 5.9ms | Allocations: 6970)
2020-04-25T01:09:46.120762+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2020-04-25T01:09:46.120706 #10] FATAL -- : [5ffafd44-806d-40e5-b0cf-fd87bdaaef67]   
2020-04-25T01:09:46.120762+00:00 app[web.1]: [5ffafd44-806d-40e5-b0cf-fd87bdaaef67] Net::SMTPAuthenticationError (535 Authentication failed: account disabled
2020-04-25T01:09:46.120763+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2020-04-25T01:09:46.120763+00:00 app[web.1]: [5ffafd44-806d-40e5-b0cf-fd87bdaaef67]   
2020-04-25T01:09:46.120763+00:00 app[web.1]: [5ffafd44-806d-40e5-b0cf-fd87bdaaef67] app/models/user.rb:50:in `send_activation_email'
2020-04-25T01:09:46.120763+00:00 app[web.1]: [5ffafd44-806d-40e5-b0cf-fd87bdaaef67] app/controllers/users_controller.rb:23:in `create'
2020-04-25T01:09:46.123840+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/users" host=mysterious-badlands-89513.herokuapp.com request_id=5ffafd44-806d-40e5-b0cf-fd87bdaaef67 fwd="24.80.110.141" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=827ms status=500 bytes=1891 protocol=https
2020-04-25T01:09:46.369543+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=mysterious-badlands-89513.herokuapp.com request_id=744e6f86-cca5-45b0-b68e-7fbc5a9ca914 fwd="24.80.110.141" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=112 protocol=https
```

Another weird thing.
When I'm trying to open the SendGrid page from the 'Resources' tab on Heroku, I just see the 'Access denied' page.

Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: That means your account is disabled like the error message suggests. You need to reach out to SendGrid support for them to enable it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My account was just banned for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined `ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME']` and `ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD']` in your Heroku account? [There is documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#using-the-heroku-dashboard) that can help with this. The error you're receiving back means that your account isn't up and running correctly. Check the credentials as I first mentioned, otherwise try to re-provision SendGrid as an add-on in Heroku.

Comment: Yes, these variables were defined automatically.